# Is there a way to run a image of node and another of Python on the same dockerfile?

Tags: python, node.js, docker

I want to put all my logic and backend in `python` and frontend in `React/Typescript` but don't know if it's possible to have a unique `Dockerfile` containing a `python image` and a `node image`.
is it the best approach to do it or should I have multiple Dockerfiles and communicate the backend and frontend with Kafka or any other message streaming framework, I'm kinda lost here!

Comment: If you're thinking about booting two docker containers from the same image which are doing two different things, you can absolutely install more than one application in a docker image, and then run the image twice with different command line arguments. for them to communicate, you'll have to set up your port forwarding or network to enable this. to get more info we'll need to know more about your setup and what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part, you should structure applications the same way whether you package them in Docker or not.  It might help to think about how you'd structure this application without Docker:

- You'd probably develop the front end (with React, npm, a `package.json` file) and back end (with Python, pip, a `setup.py` file) separately.
- If you wanted to run the React dev server, you'd separately run the Python application and the front end, in separate processes; or you could compile the React application to static files that the Python app served directly.
- The React application would make HTTP requests to the back-end application.

These translate reasonably into Docker:

- You'd build separate Docker images, one `FROM python` and one `FROM node`.
- Either you can use something like Docker Compose to run the two images in two containers, including the Webpack dev server, or you can use a multi-stage Dockerfile to build the React application into static files and then `COPY` its built content into the Python image.
- The React application still makes HTTP requests to the back-end application.

Also remember that there's no particular requirement that all of your workflow must be in Docker all the time.  If the back end depends on a database, you could run the database (only) in Docker while using a normal Python virtual environment to develop the backend.  Or, you can run the back end in a container while using webpack-dev-server to develop the front end, in a normal host Node environment, not in a container.  So long as you do a good job of declaring your library dependencies in the normal way (`package.json`; `setup.py`/`requirements.txt`/`Pipfile`) your application should run reasonably consistently in any environment, Docker or not.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean *process*, not "image".

Yes, you can install Python in a Node container, and vice-versa (`npm` is commonly added to Flask/Django containers to compile TypeScript and CSS resources, for example), but it is [not recommended](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#decouple-applications) to run more than one process per container, because you'll also need to install a "supervisor" that can actually **run both** Python and Node processes at once (and gracefully handle errors if one or both fail)

If you have a React frontend, it cannot use Kafka since that is a backend-client, and you'd therefore end up with two backends, effectively.

Sounds like you are wanting a Python service that can expose any TCP port (commonly, HTTP via a Framework like Flask or Django), then use regular AJAX fetch calls from React. While you can use a Message-Queue, that seems like overkill and would be another container, anyway if you are trying to reduce the number of running images